# using Angular 5 ReplaySubject, 'this' is not correctly inherited

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a strange problem with angular 5 and typescript (So the title of my question may not be correct).

I had this code and it works:

**calendar service**

```
_$dateChange: EventEmitter<object>;
constructor() {
    this._$dateChange = new EventEmitter<object>();
}
get $dateChange() {
    return this._$dateChange;
}
public calendarChanged(): void {
    this._$dateChange.emit({});
}
```

**parent**

```
...
y = 2;
constructor() {
    this.calendarService.$dateChange.subscribe(item => {
      this.load();
    })
}
abstract load();
```

**eventsComponent**

```
export class EventsComponent extends ParentComponent {
    x = 0;
    load() {
         console.log(this.x, this.y); // consoles 0 2
    }
}
```

So then I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40238796/1889607) and found out that I need to use ReplaySubject. Also I noticed a problem somewhere else with eventemitter.

So then I changed my code a bit. I replaced `EventEmitter` with `ReplaySubject` and `emit` with `next`. This is the modified code: (just calendar service is changed)

**calendar service**

```
_$dateChange: ReplaySubject<object>;
constructor() {
    this._$dateChange = new ReplaySubject<object>();
}
get $dateChange() {
    return this._$dateChange;
}
public calendarChanged(): void {
    this._$dateChange.next({});
}
```

And the result of console.log was `undefined 2` ! So I used `this.load().bind(this)` and it didn't change anything. I also tried to use arrow functions like this `load = () => {}` and then it gave the error that `the function load doesn't exist`.

I can't understand what the problem is but I thought it may be related to `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: Please provide code with replySubject

Comment: why do you have `abstract load()` in your code? what is inheriting from this class that has abstract method?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic the `EventsComponent` is inheriting `ParentComponent`.

Comment: It seems to me that there is an issue with inheritance here. Have a look at this question on SO. I think the problem's end result is similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819663/call-an-overridden-method-from-super-class-in-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason why this is happening.

The reason is that in parent constructor, `$dateChange` has a value so it's resolved and so `this.load();` is called. So this the code is run in this order:

1. parent constructor
2. `load` method (So `console.log(this.x, this.y);` is run here)
3. initialization of eventsComponent properties (So `x = 0;` is run here)

#### How is this related to ReplaySubject?

It's because `ReplaySubject` has a buffer and so it has the value and as a result, it's resolved immediately inside the parent constructor.